# Any chance to center this text element

Tags: html, css

I am using a managed hosting for my photography website. Customization of the website can be done only by adding CSS code.

In the following page I would like to center the text in the middle ("ROBERT POLLAI") but I cannot figure out the right CSS code to access that element.

https://www.the-ninth.com/home1

Any hints on how to achieve this are highly appreciated!

Regards, Robert

Comment: give `display: inline-block;` and `text-align: center;` to that span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add below code at the end of stylesheet.css file.

```
#content_page_wrapper h2 ._4ORMAT_content_pages_wrap #text_1 {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this CSS and it's done. As [@Joykal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10656305/joykal-infotech) has mentioned in the comment.

```
#content_page_wrapper h2 ._4ORMAT_content_pages_wrap a > span {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

edit text-align: left; from this CSS Code and text will center
and delete another two text-align: left;

```
#content_page_wrapper h2 ._4ORMAT_content_pages_wrap a{
    text-align: center;
}

content_page_wrapper h2 ._4ORMAT_content_pages_wrap #text_1{
    text-align: left;
}

#content_page_wrapper h2 {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can you text-align: center !important;
if facing issue,then also use align="center" on . so you can try.

Answer (score 0):

change the following CSS:

```
#content_page_wrapper h2 ._4ORMAT_content_pages_wrap #text_1 {
     text-align: center;
}
```